# Fsck.ext4 Input/Output error while recovering journal of / dev/ sdb and fsck.ext4: unable to set superblock flag on dev/ sdb

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, ext4

I have installed Ubuntu on my external ssd it got shutdown while i am sudo upgrade Ubuntu then i reopen again it start giving error like i/o error, superblock,dev sdb , recovery journals . I have tried many things but nothing worked

Comment: IO errors can be caused by hardware failures, have you looked?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools  though don't forget bad power causes components to *misbehave* (thus check PSU), logical errors can be caused by RAM etc.  We haven't been provide any OS/release details, so we can only be generic.